# Programmatically retrieve URL called by Spring FeignClient

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-feign

I'm trying to find a way to retrieve the URL that is currently mapped by Feign Client method interface in a Spring app, but I could not find a solution yet. The following code works:

pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

application.yml

```
api:
  url: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
```

ApiClient.class

```
package com.example.feign;

import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.FeignClient;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@FeignClient(name = "json-placeholder", url = "${api.url}")
public interface ApiClient {

    @GetMapping(value = "/posts", consumes = "application/json")
    ResponseEntity<String> getPosts();
}
```

FeignApplication.class

```
package com.example.feign;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.EnableFeignClients;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;

@EnableFeignClients
@SpringBootApplication
public class FeignApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FeignApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Autowired
    private ApiClient apiClient;

    @PostConstruct
    public void test() {

        // this works
        System.out.println(apiClient.getPosts().getBody());

        // apiClient. ... getPosts request URL
    }
}
```

I tried to compose this URL reading directly from annotations, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anybody give me an alternative? Thank you.

- EDIT notes -

Sorry, but I had do a small change in my question, due to an unexpected problem while applying provided solutions.

Reading directly from Annotations works if the value set in annotation property is literal. If the value is read from application.yml file, the URL returned by the annotation property is the expression ifself, not the parsed value.

Any ideas about this updated scenario? What I need is the URL actually been called by FeignClient. I'm understands all provided solutions are actually workarounds.

Comment: To be more clear, specified line should print `"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"`.

Comment: An easy workaround is to set the URL as a public static final String field of ApiClient, e.g. `public static final String URL = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"`. Your annotation can refer to it by using `url = ApiClient.URL`. You can then refer to this variable anywhere.

Comment: sorry, but I can do it like this. Please, see my updated statement. URL value needs to be injected as an application.yml property and will be different per environment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are still looking for the answer, but my method is below

1. Return Response

```java
import feign.Response;

@FeignClient(name = "json-placeholder", url = "${api.url}")
public interface ApiClient {

    @GetMapping(value = "/posts", consumes = "application/json")
    Response getPosts();
}
```

2. get Request.url from the Response

```java
Response response = apiClient.getPosts();
String url = response.request().url()
```

then you can get the URL